# What are the options I could use to encrypt a HTTP POST request to a web server in Android?

Tags: android, encryption

I have an android application that I send some information from the android device to my web server and the information has to be secure through the network till it reaches the server.

I was thinking about using HTTP SSL request, but maybe there are similar options that are free and secure as well.

So what are the options available to encrypt a HTTP POST request through the network?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All other options can be summarized as creating custom, proprietary and probably very broken version of SSL/TLS/HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL is definitely the best option and can be free assuming you can install certificates on the devices in question, or prompt the user to do so.  That said, it may be a red flag to users if they're prompted to install some strange certificate.  You could encrypt the payload using a symmetric encryption scheme (like `AES`) but then the issue is either key exchange (how do you get the key onto the device) or, if you use a key coded into the app, anybody could access the key from the binary.

Alternatively you could use asymmetric encryption using a server public key that is hard coded into the app, but then you also need to provide for data integrity checks etc.

In summary, just use HTTPS.  There's a 99.999999% chance whatever you write will be less secure than accepted, industry standards.

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris. I was really leaning to SSL anyway, by the way, do you know any free SSL that I could use to accomplish that?

Comment: @Grego You can create your own SSL certificate using OpenSSL (https://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt).  Usually most trusted CAs require a least a little bit of money for a certificate signature.